# Determine name of Hyper-V host of Linux guest VM

Tags: centos7, hyper-v-server-2016

I would like to be able to determine which Hyper-V host a particular CentOS 7 VM is running on. In a Windows VM this is stored in `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters`. Is anyone aware of a methodology for getting this from inside a CentOS guest?

Comment: It was noticed in far 2011 on TechNet as "preparing feature", but it looks like that Microsoft didn't add the support of this under Linux. However, if the Integration Services is installed probably the hostname of Hyper-V host can be found there.

Answer (score 0):

% strings /var/lib/hyperv/.kvp_pool_3 |head -2

Comment: That seems like an extremely fragile approach.

Comment: This points to the correct location of the file. Thanks